# Error with rendering two queries - express mongo

Tags: json, mongodb, express

I have a problem with rendering two queries from mongo database into the ejs file.

Here is my request

```
Diveplace
    .find({})
    .skip((perPage * page) - perPage)
    .limit(perPage)
    .exec(function(err, foundDiveplace) {
        Diveplace.count().exec(function(err, count) {
            if (err) return next(err)
Country.find({}, function(err, foundCountry){
  var returnVals= JSON.stringify({diveplaces: foundDiveplace, countries: foundCountry}); 

   res.render('diveplaces/index', {
                data: returnVals,
                country: foundCountry,
                current: page,
                pages: Math.ceil(count / perPage),
                          currentUser: req.user
            })
        })
    })
})
```

}
})

I try to display it on ejs page by just

```
<%= data %>
```

And it shows me whole JSON object. When i try to get deeper - data.diveplaces it gives me an error undefined.

How i can extract data from that JSON and display it? I think it's abit diffrent than single render

Answer (score 0):

Nvm. Fixed it. The problem was, the JSON wasn't actually JSON.

JSON.parse(data) helped